# What are the nets in Ender's Game? Are they based on anything in real life?

Tags: inspiration, enders-game, orson-scott-card

After reading *Ender's Game*, I liked the idea of "nets," and had some good ideas to put on there, but could never find them or what they are. Any idea, or is this just another fictional part of *Ender's Game*?

Comment: Which edition? IIRC Card had updated *Ender's Game* at least once to keep up with modern tech, so this might just be the regular internet, or Usenet, perhaps.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

'Nets' are basically the Internet as predicted/guessed by Orson Scott Card

> It is interesting to note that the World Wide Web, the modern form of the Internet, was not invented until 1990, 5 years after Ender's Game was published. Orson Scott Card accurately predicted how much influence the nets would have, years before they became a daily part of people's lives.

[Source](http://enderverse.wikia.com/wiki/Nets)

> While there’s plenty of time for Internet discussions to turn around, I suppose, I can’t help but think that Card wasn’t terribly prescient with this prediction. In Ender’s Game, “the nets” are democratic and participative — anyone can join them, as long as they have the intellect to keep up — but there’s no problem with too much noise, trolls, spammers, and plain old stupidity.

[Source](http://mediadisruptus.com/2008/08/09/enders-game-and-the-intelligent-nets/)

Some more disscussion can be found [here](http://www.hatrack.com/cgi-bin/ubbmain/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=get_topic;f=1;t=002605;p=0)

Comment: some similarities can be seen in IRC, and Usenet, which were available at the time, and would have been available to Card during his studies at the University of Notre Dame,

Answer (score 4):

Usenet, IRC, Email, and BBS systems.
Hypertext wasn't big at that point.